# Qt 6.3 FileDialog does not show "save" button on Raspberry Pi OS

Tags: linux, qt, raspberry-pi, qml, cross-compiling

Running cross compiled Qt qml application on :
Raspbian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)

Hardware RPi400

QT6.3 Cross compiled on Ubuntu 22.04

Qml code :

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Window 
import QtQuick.Dialogs
import QtQuick.Controls

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480

    FileDialog{
        id:fdSave
        fileMode:FileDialog.SaveFile
    }

    Button{
      text:"click me"
      onClicked:fdSave.open();  
    }

}
```

Expected behaviour textfield for new filename and a "save" button.
Result :

[image: Result of calling FileDialog]

Comment: Please report the bug to https://bugreports.qt.io

Comment: You think it's a bug ?

Comment: Could be - it is at least weird.

Comment: It looks like as if the type was not respected because it just opens a usual file open dialog, rather than file save. Check if C++ works.

Comment: the same code shows correct FileDialog in Ubuntu.

Comment: Have you reported this bug?